# Node.js delete user from cognito

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I am using this code to delete user from aws cognito

This section will help you delete customer.

```
    userController.deleteUser = async function (req, res) {
        const query = { _id: req.params.id };
    
        // delete user from congnito
        const user = await User.findOne(query);
        AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        region: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_REGION,
        });
        const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
    
        await cognito
        .adminDeleteUser({
            UserPoolId: "a7260b2f-487b-4a2b-935e-029009ee0b6b",
            Username: user.email,
        })
        .promise();
    

        return res.status(200).send({ msg: `${query.id} deleted` });
    };
```

error :

```
    /Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/cnox/cnoxbackend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52
    resp.error = util.error(new Error(), error);
                            ^

    InvalidParameterException: 1 validation error detected: Value 'us-west-2:a7260b2f-487b-4a2b-935e-029009ee0b6b' at 'userPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w-]+_[0-9a-zA-Z]+
```

I am getting above error when making request, Please check if user pool id is correct ?
Not sure where it is breaking.

Getting user poolid from here below screenshot is it correct ?

[image]

Please take a look how can i solve this error.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

For `adminDeleteUser` function, `UserPoolId` should be the user pool ID for the user pool where you want to delete the user.

In your case, `UserPoolId` should be `us-east-1_mGp3WP...`

then your code will look like this:

```
        await cognito
            .adminDeleteUser({
                UserPoolId: "us-east-1_mGp3WP...",
                Username: "a7260b2f-487b-4a2b-935e-029009ee0b6b", // user.username or req.params.id ???
            })
            .promise();
```